# Wrong answer accepted

Tags: discussion

Hi

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395372/how-does-wikitude-know-my-location/1401568#1401568) keeps nagging me. There are two answers, one which is accepted and then mine. And I can help but believe that the accepted answer is simply incorrect. Yet it got far more votes and got accepted by the OP.

What can I do about it? And should I even bother?

Comment: You shouldn't bother, because the question is off-topic anyway and should be closed as such.

Comment: Happens. Don't bother, move on, answer other stuff. Do you think Jon Skeet cares when one of his answers isn't accepted? No, because in the mean time he's already answered (and been accepted) for dozens of others.

Comment: It's also a 1 year old question. Does it bother you so much that you have to post about it 1 year later? :P

Comment: The question is a year old, closed, and you're currently at a tied score with the accepted answer -- it's hard to find an injustice less severe to worry about :)

Comment: @Michael: Well all of this (closed and the tied score) happened just during the last day. :)

Comment: In my situation, my answer gets no upvote and not accepted by the OP, while a similar (almost identical) answer post 3 minutes after mine got both... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345666/hiding-a-form-and-showing-another-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-a-windows-forms-app/4345702#4345702

Answer (score 2):

It will happen.  Period.  Forget it.  Here's an idea: Maybe your answer wasn't actually the best answer.  It happens to everyone.  Be happy with the 5 upvotes you got and move along.