# Wrong answer is accepted: what to do?

Tags: discussion, moderation

What is my desired action whether I see that totally (well, partially) wrong answer was accepted by question owner as correct? E.g. I see the productivity/readability/you-name-it issues with a suggested solution, but the answer somehow has the problem resolved and hence was marked as correct?

What am I supposed to do in such a case?

**UPD** that is not dup, I examined the relatives thoroughly. I am interested in a case when I’m non-related to discussion at all, but I clearly see, that the answer accepted has leaks. And my question is: “What am I supposed to do?” Leaving intact leads to effort to discredit the resource (what’s indeed not the goal,) disrating an answer makes no sence as well.

Comment: Nothing whatsoever. It is up to the OP to select whatever answer he wants to accept. You can perhaps politely point out how the answer is incorrect by commenting on the answer. But that's about it.

Comment: Downvote the answer and explain why it's wrong in a comment.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71380/wrong-answer-accepted. Or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139307/wrong-answer-marked-accepted

Comment: That’s noticeable that SO became a trusted resource. If the OP selected the answer as correct, that _actually_ means, that his task was completed. `(1..5).map{ |m| if m%2 == 0 ; 1 ; else 0 ; end }.inject(0){ |sum, e| sum += e }` does solve the problem _“count all the evens within a range”_. But it’s definitely not a best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voting should ensure the best answer is shown on top. Often this is the accepted answer, but not always.

If you know the accepted answer is incorrect, down-vote it and/or add a comment. If another answer is better, ensure you up-vote that. If none of the answers is correct, then add your own.

Comment: Well, I understand the meaning of up- and down-votes. I’m anxious about those who will find the answers years later. They will simply use a pattern “accepted ⇒ correct”. Anyway, thanks for reply, I understood that top answer is more reliable, than the accepted one. Should we put this in wiki?